Is there an adjoint functor theorem specific to algebraic categories?
I am using the term algebraic category to mean a category of algebras for a finite-product theory, as in the book Algebraic Theories.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be algebraic categories, and let $F: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ be a functor. The goal is to determine when $F$ has a left adjoint. Noting that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are locally finitely presentable categories, we know that $F$ has a left adjoint if $F$ preserves small limits and filtered colimits.
It is a theme of the book Algebraic Theories that sifted colimits replace filtered colimits in the context of algebraic categories. So suppose that in the above situation we know that $F$ preserves sifted colimits (which is stronger than just preserving filtered colimits). Provided that we have strengthened the hypothesis of preserving filtered colimits, can we weaken the hypothesis of preserving small limits (say, weaken to limits of a certain type)?

I don't know a weakening of the conditions on the right adjoint, but note that such a functor is equivalent to a finite coproduct-preserving functor between the subcategories of strongly finite objects in $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B.$ I suspect you're more likely to just look for such a "presenting" functor, rather than for the kind of adjoint functor theorem statement you're after, because the theorem for locally presentable categories really characterizes cocontinuous functors between them, whereas the lack of a distinct notion of $\lambda$-sifted colimit means the same can't happen here.

In the specific case of varieties of algebras (i.e. categories of sets equipped with some set of finitary relations satisfying some set of identities -- e.g. groups, rings, $R$-modules for fixed ring $R$, pointed sets, but not fields), there's a theorem that $F : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{D}$ has a left adjoint if and only it's representable by a co-$\mathbf{D}$ object of $\mathbf{C}$.  I don't know if something similar happens for more general algebraic categories.

@DanielSchepler that sounds like it is in the direction of what I'm looking for. Do you have a reference for that theorem?

It's in George Bergman's category theory notes.  I might be able to look up a more detailed reference later today, if you want.

@DanielSchepler thanks, i think i found it in section 9.4 here https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.0.pdf

Yes, that's it, theorem 9.4.3.

I believe that result holds whenever $\mathbf C$ is cocomplete and $\mathbf D$ has a dense generator, so is not specific to algebraic categories. In particular, it holds for locally presentable categories.
